# XML parsing tries to parse more lines then exist

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have a strange problem when parsing an xml request with JAXB: somehow it tries to parse more lines then exists in the string:

```
String xml; //content with 139 lines in xml format
MyReq req = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml), MyReq.class);
```

Result:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 140; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in trailing section.
```

What might be wrong with this?? The lines does not exist that is supposed to be have an error...

I can copy the xml just as it is to soapUI and execute the request successfully, thus concluding the xml is valid in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the `xml` content. Most of the time `Content is not allowed in trailing section` error is because the content is not valid, probably some bad characters at the end of the stream.

You should print the content of the xml, with some known delimiters, to ensure that what you received is what you actually tested/expected, something like:

```
System.out.println("*"+xml+"*");
```

Comment: Sorry, just added above that I can execute the xml as request in soapui successfully. So I assume the xml should be correct in general?

Comment: @membersound Are you sure that you are using the same xml that the one that is parsed? See my updated answer for a way to print the xml message just before the parse.

Comment: Yes with that I'm sure I indeed use the same xml.

Comment: @membersound Can you provide the output of the `System.out.println("*"+xml+"*");` line?

Comment: At the end you were right, there was some noise at the end that did not belong to the xml.